# Changing next button to done button on soft keyboard doesn't work

Tags: android

When the user clicks an icon in the action bar, an AlertDialog opens to save the data.
To enter the name of the file, a soft keyboard appears. In this keyboard I want to change the ENTER button with a DONE. I applied ".setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);" but it doesn't work. This is my code for the AlertDialog:

public void openSaveBox (){

```
    final AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    ad.setTitle("OCRA score bewaren");
    ad.setMessage("Geef een bestandsnaam in:");
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);        
    ad.setView(input);

    ad.setButton2("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String file = input.getText().toString();
            bewaren(file);
            ad.dismiss();
        }
    });
    ad.setButton("Annuleren", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ad.dismiss();
        }
    });

    ad.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

    ad.show();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Set the `InputType` for the Edit text input before `ImeOptions` i.e

```
  input.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
  input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

Comment: @Michael_D if it worked you should accept the answer